# Workbooks in Log Analytics Workspace vs Workbooks in Azure Monitor

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I can see there is a section called workbooks with same icon in both Log Analytics and in Monitor. What is the differende betwen the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same thing, if you click the `?Help` button, you will find they point to the same [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-overview).

[image]

The difference is there are some different templates on the two pages, and if you add something e.g. the new query or metric in a new report, the one in the Log Analytics Workspace will select the values related to the workspace, the one in the Monitor will not select the default value like below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks appreciated. If starting from scratch, and you had to monitor around 50 applications on application insights only. Would you create a Log Analytics Workspace or just create workbooks in Monitor?

Comment: @ThomasSegato I will create a workspace, it is better to manage, becasue there are other users in my subscription.

Comment: Makes sense thanks. There is a lot of articles stating you should only have one workspace pr tenant. Sounds weird right?

Comment: @ThomasSegato I have never heard about this, it is just a normal azure resource located in the subscription, and there also can be many subscriptions in one tenant.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated.

Comment: I only see one workbook. There is no way to create another. I am the admin. I am talking about 'Workbooks' not the Monitor Workbook